# How can I switch the underlying markup of a Svelte component without an "if"?

Tags: svelte

Can anyone suggest a better way to implement a component that can either be an `a` or a `button`?  I'm ok with this approach but everything is duplicated between them except the `href` on the `a` and the `on:click` on the `button`:

```
{#if url}
  <a class="button {classes}"
     class:button--solid={!outlined}
     class:button--outlined={outlined}
     {disabled}
     bind:this={element}
     href={url}
     >
    <span class="label"><slot /></span>
  </a>
{:else}
  <button class="button {classes}"
          class:button--solid={!outlined}
          class:button--outlined={outlined}
          {disabled}
          bind:this={element}
          on:click
          >
    <span class="label"><slot /></span>
  </button>
{/if}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As proposed earlier, you can use `<svelte:component>` but I suppose that's too overkill for your use case (you need to create 2 separate components just for vanilla `button` and `a`). It seems like you only need better readability. A workaround to get more DRY would be to use [spread props](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/spread-props).

```
<script>
    export let url;
    const classes = 'class-1 class-2';
    const outlined = true;
    const disabled = true;
    $: props = {
        class: `button ${classes} ${outlined ? 'button--outlined' : 'button--solid'}`,
        disabled
    }
</script>

{#if url}
    <a {...props} href={url}><slot/></a>
{:else}
    <button {...props} on:click><slot/></button>
{/if}
```

Comment: yep, you totally get it, I agree, the `<svelte:component>` seems a little over-engineered for my taste personally.

Answer (score 0):

you can use <svelte:component this={selected.component}/>

Have a look here: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-component